# MySQL Client out of memory when running a simple select query from MSSQL ODBC

Tags: mysql-5.7, memory

Table has a total of 1,120,000 rows and 20 columns. When I run a select query on mysql directly like:

```
select * from <tablename> where UpdatedOn > '2020-10-05'
```

it gives the results which is about 50+ rows.

But when I run the same from MSSQL using ODBC Connection it throws "MySQL Client Out of Memory" every single time.

- The server has 8 GB RAM and no one else is using the server
- Running Select top gives the results without the error
- Running select with a single integer column like select id from ... throws a "MySQL Client out of memory"

What could be going wrong? I haven't been able to the issue.

Comment: How is "UpdatedOn" defined in the MySQL DB?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille UpdatedOn is a field with type datetime

Comment: What versions of MSSQL and ODBC?   Your MySQL could do with an update.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille ```mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.31```

Answer (score 0):

The comparison of datetime with a string may cause odbc to retrieve the entire table before eliminating rows.  Either compare with a datetime constant or set the prefetch parameter in the odbc config to a reasonable value.

Comment: Tried ```select count(*) FROM [Appserver]...[DB.Tablename]
where updatedon > cast('2020-10-05' as datetime)``` did not work. Same error "MySQL Client Out Of Memory"

Comment: I don't think ODBC understands a "cast".  Can you try with a 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:hh:ss' format string?   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-date-time/data-type-support-for-odbc-date-and-time-improvements?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Problem: according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-date-time/datetime-data-type-conversions-odbc?view=sql-server-ver15, your '2020-10-05' should have worked.  Did you try the prefetch parameter?